# How to get unchecked row/checkbox value in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, checkbox

I am using `<lightning:datatable onrowselection="{!c.onSelectContact}" />` for displaying contacts and to check and uncheck checkbox fields.

Then in the component controller i use event.getParam('selectedRows') to get all the selected rows.

Question: How can i find out which particular checkbox has been unchecked because if i use event.getParam('selectedRows') the unchecked row is not part of the selectedRows array.

One way would be to keep a separate list of selected row Ids - but why the overhead? How can i just get the information that certain row/checkbox field is unchecked?

contactList.cmp

```
<lightning:datatable onrowselection="{!c.onSelectContact}" />
```

contactListController.js

```
onSelectContact: function(component, event, helper) {
     var selectedRows= event.getParam('selectedRows');
}
```

What i want to know is if i select a row i can see it as part of the selectedRows list but if i want to unselect the row `event.getParam('selectedRows')` does not have the information of the previously selected row. **Basically is there a way to get row id during uncheck of a row**

Comment: @owsata your code does not show what you are doing, please attach full datatable code so we can see and try to help

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute of type List as a helper attribute to hold old data --
Try the below code...

**yourComponent.cmp** - *add the attribute*

```
<aura:attribute name="oldData" type="List" default="[]"/>
```

On your table selection event add this code ---

```
updateSelectedText: function (component, event) {

    var oldData = component.get("v.oldData");
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');

    if(oldData.length == 0){
        component.set("v.oldData", selectedRows);
    }else if(selectedRows.length < oldData.length){

        var onlyInOld = selectedRows.filter(comparer(oldData));
        var onlyInNew = oldData.filter(comparer(selectedRows));

        //List of all unselected objects from dataTable
        var unselectedData = onlyInOld.concat(onlyInNew);
        console.log("your unselected data", unselectedData);

    }else if(selectedRows.length > oldData.length){
        component.set("v.oldData", selectedRows);
    }

    //helper comparer function
    function comparer(otherArray){
        return function(current){
            return otherArray.filter(function(other){
                return other.Id == current.Id
            }).length == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the javaScript code, you will finally have your list of objects which has been unselected. This line -

```
var unselectedData = onlyInOld.concat(onlyInNew);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Avinash - thanks for providing this code. It works great except it looks like you have the assignments of onlyInOld and onlyInNew flipped around. When I ran your code as-is, I got the UNCHECKED values in the OnlyInNew variable and the CHECKED values in the onlyInOld. Corrected code snippet: var onlyInNew = selectedRows.filter(comparer(oldData)); var onlyInOld = oldData.filter(comparer(selectedRows));